# Ensure a number is a factor of another number

Tags: java

I need to ensure that values passed to one of my classes fit onto a grid with cells of 4px

So if 16 gets passed

```
16%4==0 //this is fine
```

however

```
17%4==1 //not ok
```

I need the program to convert the value to fit on the grid, so in the last case 17 would be converted to 16 (round down), if it were 19 it would get converted to 20 (round up) etc.

So is there a library that will do this for me?

Comment: @jax: You have to define your rounding first. For example: 18,  does it get rounded up or down?

Comment: How would 17 items fit on a 4x4 grid? I think you should be always rounding up.

Comment: A good way to flesh this out is by writing the unit test first for all values that needs to be correct.  This very frequently makes it extremely easy to see how it should be done.  In your case, write a testcase for all numbers from 1 to 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, including the rounding up part.

```
int gridVal = (((int) val + 2) / 4) * 4
```

Edit for completeness:

If you want to round 18 down, then use this statment.

```
int gridVal = (((int) val + 1) / 4) * 4
```

If you want to deal with negative values as well, then you need a conditional.

```
int gridVal = ((val >= 0 ? (int) val + 2 : (int) val - 2) / 4) * 4
```

Edit for variable (even) grid size:

```
int halfGrid = gridSize / 2;
int gridVal = ((val >= 0 ? (int) val + halfGrid : (int) val - halfGrid) / gridSize) * gridSize;
```

Comment: for 18,its going to 16 not fullfilling the question requirement

Comment: What if I change my grid size?  Say I have a constant CELL_SIZE=16, how would I apply this to the current formula?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
val = val - (val % 4)
```

Now with rounding

```
val = Round(val / 4) * 4
```

Comment: nice an simple thanks, it does not round up but maybe it doesn't matter

Comment: @jax, missed the whole round up thing, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

Devide by the number, then Round and multiply by the number.

Something like

```
val = Round(val / 4) * 4
```